# Compare the rows of 2 tables in 2 different databases

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have 2 different databases. In both there is a table called fruit. Now I want to update the second database with respect to the first database. For this I compare each row by all column values (except the ID column) in the first database to each row in the second database and get those rows in which there is a difference. the query i am using is

```
SELECT A.* FROM db1.Fruit A 
           Left Outer Join Fruit B ON 
           (A.Ratings = B.Ratings  AND A.Name = B.Name  AND A.Color = B.Color) 
where B.Ratings  IS NULL OR B.Name  IS NULL OR B.Color  IS NULL
```

[Table in the first database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIzRg.jpg)[Table in the second database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9gXu.jpg).

Now in the result it should show the the row with ID 3 where the name is Kiwi and the color is green. But it also shows the row with ID 4 with name Banana as the other columns is null and in my query I am writing that return the row if `B.Ratings IS NULL or B.Color IS NULL`.

So is there any other way to compare 1 row of table one to 1 row of table 2 by all columns (except ID column) and return those rows in which there is a mismatch in any of the column values?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code is best understood when reading code instead of its translation to english. Please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

I have been confused :) 
Edited: 
I getting back to my initial response

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM db1.Fruit as A JOIN db2.Fruit as B ON 
(A.Name = B.Name  AND A.Color = B.Color )
WHERE A.Rating <> B.Rating
```

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would gives the rows with Nulls on the left side (and you will see the right part of it); which is not what you want to do (at least that's my current understanding).
This statement will give you: the information on the db1 which have the same Name and Color as in the db2 but the Rating is different (which I thought is what you want to get).
If you want to change the combination of columns you have to change the join.

Comment: Inner join would give me the rows which are different in both. I need only those which are there in first but not in the second. So which should I use ? Also I wanted to know the use of <> operator and what to do when ratings or name or color any one can be different should we do B.Name<>A.Name and B.Color<>A.Color ?

Comment: I want to get those rows which are there in first but not in the second database. Also i want to select the rows based on combination of columns. I could have done it by using EXCEPT or MINUS command but the issue with that is it compares all the columns . I don't want to compare the ID column(ID can be different but the rest of the column values should be the same). Also if the value is null in those columns in both databases, it should not return that row.The command I have mentioned above also returns those rows in which the value in both db is null for that column. How can I do that ?